# Null params in method of web-service

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I use Jersey for WS.
I have the following method:

```
@Path("...")
@POST
public Response updateConfigs(@Context HttpServletRequest request, ....
        ConfigurationItemList itemList) {
    ...
}
```

Where itemList is POST param. When I try to call this method with empty POST params, I get an exception:

```
[#|2012-10-12T14:08:52.623+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2173)
       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2106)
       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1004)
       ...
|#]

[#|2012-10-12T14:08:52.624+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[...ApplicationConfig]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet ....ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2173)
       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2106)
       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1004)
       at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
       ....
|#]
```

Comment: What `@Consumes` annotation do you use? How is `ConfigurationItemList` mapped from/to JSON/XML/...?

Comment: `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` Convert is made by Jersey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the only possible workaround is to use your own JAX-RS data provider, which will properly handle incoming `NULL`s. See also: [JAX-RS / Jersey how to customize error handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583973/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-customize-error-handling)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, MessageBodyReader it's solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get

> java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

is what I would expect for an empty input. Since there is no JSON to consume, what do you expect JAX-RS to do?

**Edit:** In JAX-RS 2.0, [validation will be included](http://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/pages/Validation).

Comment: I want catch this exception.