# Consume Restful method from URL with Date Param Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have a restful web service method like this one:

```
@GET
@Path("/generateInfo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String generateInfo(
        @QueryParam("a") String a,
        @QueryParam("b") String b, 
        @QueryParam("date") Date date) {
    // ...business code...
    return "hello world";
}
```

How can I invoke that method from a WebBrowser?, the problem is the `Date` param that when i try is giving me `404` not found or `500` internal server error.

Comment: Will passing milliseconds work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest accepting the date as a `String` and parsing it yourself. Like so:

```
@GET
@Path("/generateInfo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String generateInfo(
        @QueryParam("a") String a,
        @QueryParam("b") String b, 
        @QueryParam("date") String date) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date dateObj = sdf.parse(date);

    return "hello world";
}
```

The way to make this request via a browser is:

```
http://localhost/your_service/generateInfo?date=2013-02-14
```

Things to consider when parsing dates:

- `SimpleDateFormat` is very flexible with parsing different date formats. The [ISO standard for date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings is: `yyyy-MM-dd`
- The [Joda Java date API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is accepted as a more complete implementation of date/time, and [some believe that it is more optimised than Java's native date API](http://mike-java.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/java-date-time-api-vs-joda.html) particularly for parsing dates.
- it is often better to provide dates as epoch timestamps, especially if your application operates over different timezones. However, you must be aware of HTTP caching issues when accepting epoch timestamps (e.g. if your clients are not truncating epoch timestamps then you will get lots of cache misses). I would refer back to [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) as formatted dates are easier to HTTP cache.

Comment: This is the preferred way IMHO. Your JSON marshaller most likely will break down the `Date` class into it's fields, so you'd end up with an object `Date` in your JSON, rather then a neat `String`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format of the date in the URL.
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583973/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-customize-error-handling), any format that the constructor `Date(String)` can handle should work. If your date format is different and you cannot change it, you'll have to go with pestrella's solution and receive the date as a string and convert it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET
@Path("/generateInfo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public String generateInfo(
 @QueryParam("a") String a,   
 @QueryParam("b") String b, 
 @QueryParam("date") String str_date) {

 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

 Date date = df.parse(str_date);
 return "hello world";
}
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of the accepted answer with just minor changes in variable names.