# Override DropWizard ConstraintViolation message

Tags: java, jax-rs, dropwizard

So I want to change the validation messages used to validate a model through a DropWizard resource.

I'm using java bean validation annotations. For example here is one of the fields I want to validate:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Password must not be empty.")
```

I can test this works as expected using a validator.

However when I use DropWizard to do the validation on the resource it adds some extra stuff to that message. What I see is this - `password Password must not be empty. (was null)` and I've found the code that does this here - https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-validation/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/validation/ConstraintViolations.java

Specifically this method -

```
public static <T> String format(ConstraintViolation<T> v) {
    if (v.getConstraintDescriptor().getAnnotation() instanceof ValidationMethod) {
        final ImmutableList<Path.Node> nodes = ImmutableList.copyOf(v.getPropertyPath());
        final ImmutableList<Path.Node> usefulNodes = nodes.subList(0, nodes.size() - 1);
        final String msg = v.getMessage().startsWith(".") ? "%s%s" : "%s %s";
        return String.format(msg,
                             Joiner.on('.').join(usefulNodes),
                             v.getMessage()).trim();
    } else {
        return String.format("%s %s (was %s)",
                             v.getPropertyPath(),
                             v.getMessage(),
                             v.getInvalidValue());
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can override this behaviour? I just want to display the message that I set in the annotation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/2655ac703a0f6ddb4eae933a74dae3d12fde287f/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/validation/ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.java) is the one which uses that method. In order to override it, you need to deregister it and register your own [ExceptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185299/jax-rs-jersey-exceptionmappers-user-defined-exception).

**Remove the exception mapper(s)**

[Dropwizard 0.8](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/710)

Add the following to your yaml file. Note that it will remove all the default exception mappers that dropwizard adds.

```
server:
    registerDefaultExceptionMappers: false
```

[Dropwizard 0.7.x](http://thoughtspark.org/2013/02/25/dropwizard-and-jersey-exceptionmappers/)

```
environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().getSingletons().removeIf(singleton -> singleton instanceof ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper);
```

**Create and add your own exception mapper**

```
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        // get the violation errors and return the response you want.
    }
}
```

and add your exception mapper in your application class.

```
public void run(T configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
  environment.jersey().register(ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.class);
}
```

Comment: I like [Lukasz Wiktor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30799426/1891566) better 'cause he re-instates the other exception mappers that the first step of this answer removes, effectively changing *only the mapper for `ConstraintValidationException`s*

Answer (score 9):

Here is a programmatic solution in dropwizard 0.8:

```
public void run(final MyConfiguration config, final Environment env) {
    AbstractServerFactory sf = (AbstractServerFactory) config.getServerFactory();
    // disable all default exception mappers
    sf.setRegisterDefaultExceptionMappers(false);
    // register your own ConstraintViolationException mapper
    env.jersey().register(MyConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.class)
    // restore other default exception mappers
    env.jersey().register(new LoggingExceptionMapper<Throwable>() {});
    env.jersey().register(new JsonProcessingExceptionMapper());
    env.jersey().register(new EarlyEofExceptionMapper());
}
```

I think it's more reliable than a config file. And as you can see it also enables back all other [default exception mappers](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v0.8.1/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server/AbstractServerFactory.java#L480).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the current one removes more exception mappers than what the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

@ValidationMethod should be useful here. isn't it?

http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.0/docs/manual/validation.html

```
@ValidationMethod(message="Password cannot be empty")
@JsonIgnore
public boolean isPasswordProvided() {
    return false if password not provided;
}
```