# Catch json processing exception with dropwizard?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard application with a global exception handler registered that implements `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>`. If I throw any runtime exception from within a resource the mapper gets hit.

However, in a test I am posting JSON to to a resource with a missing type discriminator for a jackson polymorphic type.  Jersey is returning a 400, and I can see that a `JsonProcessingException` is being thrown when stepping through the code, but the global mapper isn't getting hit.

I tried to see if there were any other exception mappers registered and to try and unregister them, by checking the `environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().getSingletons()` set and there were no other exception mappers registered.

I've also tried creating a specific handler for just that exception but no dice. And even then that's kind of weird if I already have a global handler to catch all Throwable.

Has anyone encountered this?

--

EDIT:

looks like the dropwizard exception mapper does get registered and I somehow need to find out when in the lifecycle that happens and unregister it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do need to override the exception mapper for `JsonProcessingException` ([`JsonProcessingExceptionMapper`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v0.8.1/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/jackson/JsonProcessingExceptionMapper.java)).

> looks like the dropwizard exception mapper does get registered and I somehow need to find out when in the lifecycle that happens and unregister it

You can find out how to override an ExceptionMapper on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806959/override-dropwizard-constrainviolation-message/29059976#29059976).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I was wondering why I wasn't able to unregister them and its because I am using dropwizard 8 with jersey 2, so the flag in that answer is perfect.