# How to solve produce xml in java rest services with jersey?

Tags: java, json, xml, web-services, jersey

I am creating simple web services using jersey.

Here all are working but i'm not able get data as xml format now i am using json format for display data for this json display i added jersey-media-moxy dependency, i don't know i need to add any xml dependency.

This is my pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.vz.mongodb.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-jackson-mapper</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is my resouce

```
@Path("student")
public class StudentResource {

private static Map<Integer, Students> stud_data = new HashMap<Integer, Students>();

static{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        Students stu = new Students();
        int id = i+1;
        stu.setId(id);
        stu.setName("My Student "+id);
        stu.setAge(new Random().nextInt(15)+1);

        stud_data.put(id, stu);
    }
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Students> getall(){
    return new ArrayList<Students>(stud_data.values());
}
}
```

Please help me, how can i display the xml data like json.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)`? You can have more than one media type, just add them in between `{.., ..}` separated by comma. You also need to make sure to set the `Accept` header on the request to which type you want.

Comment: i just give @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML), but display error message HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: Add one of [these ExceptionMapper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15185615/2587435). But use the generic type `Exception`, i.e. `ExceptionMapper<Exception>`. My guess is it is a JAXB exception being thrown that is not handled by an exception mapper. Just print the stacktrace in the mapper. If you see a stacktrace, please post it.

Comment: Also make sure the `Student` class is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`

Answer (score 3):

According to [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html), you can either use Moxy or JAXB RI to convert objects to xml documents. If you want to use Moxy you need to do some further configurations which are [defined here](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e9049). But if you want to use reference implementation add jaxb dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

First you must annotate your classes with proper jaxb annotations. Here is an example (not minimal simple @XmlRootElement will also works).

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "user", propOrder = {
        "id",
        "name",
        "email"
})
public class StudentDto {

    @XmlElement(name = "id", nillable = false, required = false)
    private Long id;

    @XmlElement(name = "name", nillable = true, required = true)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "email", nillable = false, required = false)
    private String email;

    // GETTERS && SETTERS
}
```

Then you must annotate your services that they can both consume and produce XML  documents. For example

```
@Path("student")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class StudentResource {

}
```

And finally your client must use proper headers, to tell server what kind of request it is doing and what kind of response it is waiting. Here is these headers

```
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
```

Which means in order to run getAllStudents service you need to execute something like (update: do not need Content-Type since there is no content in get. Thanks @peeskillet for comment) this.

```
curl -i \
    -H "Accept: application/xml" \
    -X GET \
    http://your_endpoint:8080/your_context/your_root_path/student
```

Comment: Content-Type is not required for GET (unless you're actually send data). There's no content being sent to have a type for :-)

Comment: Awesome, adding a dependency on jersey-media-jaxb solved my problem.