# RESTful: return error code in place of JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, post

I have this POST method in RESTful:

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String doPostJson(String string) {
    ...
}
```

Normally it gets JSON and returns JSON. If I face an incorrect JSON in received parameter I would like to return error code "400 Bad Request". How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to return error code 400, you should change the Response header when you return to caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw `WebApplicationException` from your code when you got an incorrect JSON. Might be better idea to extend `WebApplicationException` if you use this exception in other places as well.

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
```

You can see more detailed on `WebApplicationException` here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html

And list of the `Response.Status` here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html

Another good read in SO related to this:
[JAX-RS / Jersey how to customize error handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583973/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-customize-error-handling)

Comment: I solved it already:) Thanks for confirming this is the correct way to go.