# Dropwizard - how to do a server side redirect from a view?

Tags: java, view, dropwizard

I'm new to [Drop Wizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/), and would like to redirect from a server side view to another url in my app.

Does DropWizard wrap up this common task somehow?

e.g.

```
@GET
public View getView(@Context HttpServletRequest req)
{
     View view = new View();

     if (somethingBad)
     {
         // code here to redirect to another url, eg /bad_data
     }
     else
     {
          return view;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a simple code example that actually does the redirect using a WebApplicationException. So you could put this in your view, or in your resource, and just throw it whenever.

```
URI uri2 = UriBuilder.fromUri(url).build();
Response response = Response.seeOther(uri2).build();
throw new WebApplicationException(response);
```

You can also just make your resource return either a view, or a redirect response:

```
@GET
public Object getView(@Context HttpServletRequest req)
{
     if (somethingBad())
     {
         URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("/somewhere_else").build();
         return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
     }

     return new View();
}
```

Comment: Use `javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder` and save 7 lines of code (no need to deal with an Exception), e.g. `URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("/publisher/{id}").build(publisher.getId());`

Comment: Except you took out the essential `Response response = Response.seeOther(uri2).build();` step! :)

Comment: Heads-up, if you are using Dropwizard Hibernate - throwing the Exception will cause your transaction to be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Dropwizard is using Jersey 1.x. In Jersey you can throw a WebApplicationException to redirect a user.

Also see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/599131/360594

Comment: Excellent... that appears to be it...  throwing it with a 307 (or 302) Response will work.

Comment: Throwing an exception for an expected behaviour of "redirect" is bad design IMHO. Not downvoting, though.