# Prefered way to redirect http connection to https in Dropwizard

Tags: java, redirect, https, http-redirect, dropwizard

I'd like to redirect incoming http connections to https in Dropwizard, preferably togglable in a config file (e.g. with a YAML file, like other connection attributes).
[I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20709386/1092672), and I'm reasonably certain that it's not a solution]

A solution I've found in [several](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/NAWbO5xr19Q) [places](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/download/attachments/45875790/SecureRedirectFilter.java?version=1&modificationDate=1278337292000) involves hooking in a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that checks the schema, and if it finds "http", calls sendRedirect with a modified URL. This involves hardcoding the behavior to make this always happen though.

If I extend the [HttpConnectorFactory](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jetty/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jetty/HttpConnectorFactory.java), it seems like I could add configuration in the YAML for whether I want the redirection to happen. However, it's unclear to me how complicated it will be to add an attribute without breaking other code.

This seems like a common task; is there a standard, "preferred" way to do this? I would have expected Dropwizard to have elegant built-in support, [like Jetty does](https://serverfault.com/q/367660), but I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know that there's a "preferred" way to do this but how about something like this (for Dropwizard 0.7.0):

```java
void addHttpsForward(ServletContextHandler handler) {
  handler.addFilter(new FilterHolder(new Filter() {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
      StringBuffer uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL();
      if (uri.toString().startsWith("http://")) {
        String location = "https://" + uri.substring("http://".length());
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(location);
      } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
    }

    public void destroy() {}
  }), "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
}

@Override
public void run(ExampleConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
  //...
  if (configuration.forwardHttps()) {
    addHttpsForward(environment.getApplicationContext());
  }
  //...      
}
```

You'd just need to add a boolean to your application configuration and then you could easily switch https forwarding with your YAML.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the redirect bundle at

https://github.com/dropwizard-bundles/dropwizard-redirect-bundle

```
@Override
public void initialize(final Bootstrap<PrmCatchConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new RedirectBundle(new HttpsRedirect(false)));
```

Above HttpsRedirect is constructed with false for allowPrivateIps which makes testing things locally possible. HttpsRedirect docs has plenty of information on this.