# Dropwizard resource classes calling another resource method classes?

Tags: java, json, dropwizard

I was wondering if it was possible in dropwizard to call another resource method class from a different resource class.

I looked around other posts and using ResourceContext allows one to call a get method from another resource class, but it also possible to use a post method from another resource class.

Let say we have two resource classes A and B. In class A, I have created some JSON and I want to post that JSON to B class using B's post method. Would that be possible?

Comment: You want to call one B's method from A? Certainly you can do that just like any other method call, however you need to have the instance of B in A. If you want to make an HTTP POST call to another url (B), you can make use of an httpclient (jersey or apache httpclient for example). Or simply you can have a redirection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709386/dropwizard-how-to-do-a-server-side-redirect-from-a-view

Answer (score 6):

Yes, **Resource Context** can be used to access both `POST` and `GET` methods from another method in same or different resource. 
With the help of `@Context`, you can easily access the methods.

```
@Path("a")
class A{
    @GET
    public Response getMethod(){
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
    @POST
    public Response postMethod(ExampleBean exampleBean){
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

You can now access the methods of `Resource A` from `Resource B` in the following manner.

```
@Path("b")
class B{
    @Context 
    private javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceContext rc;

    @GET
    public Response callMethod(){
        //Calling GET method
        Response response = rc.getResource(A.class).getMethod();

        //Initialize Bean or paramter you have to send in the POST method
        ExampleBean exampleBean = new ExampleBean();

        //Calling POST method
        Response response = rc.getResource(A.class).postMethod(exampleBean);

        return Response.ok(response).build();
    }
}
```