# calling an endpoint from another resource

Tags: java, annotations, jax-rs

I'm trying to call an endpoint/Resource from another resource

I guess I should use `@Context` and `ResourceContext` but not sure exactly how

here's a sample code

```
@Path("/A")
public class ClassA {

    @Context
    ResourceContext resourceContext;

    @GET
    public void functionA(){
         // call classB.functionB:
         // Response response = resourceContext.getResource(ClassB.class).functionB();
    }
```

```
@Path("/B")
public class ClassB {
    @Context
    ResourceContext resourceContext;

    @GET
    public void functionB(){
         // do something
    }
}
```

looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40454790/3609252) looks like I should call the second endpoint (from `classA`) with

`Response response = resourceContext.getResource(ClassB.class).functionB();`

But since `resourceContext` is `null` it throws an error.

so how should I initialize it or is there anything else I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance