# Jersey to customize error handling for invalid resource path?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

[This is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583973/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-customize-error-handling), but mine is more specific.

If I type in an invalid resource path, like /foobar, it returns a 404.  I'd like this to return a 400.  400 is "bad request".  I feel like this is more informative to the client.  How I can configure Jersey 1.x to return this instead?

Comment: Why do you have that feeling? What about it makes it a bad request as defined in the HTTP spec?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in the sense that the client has [definitely made a mistake and should not try again](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1).  I feel a 404 is more appropriate for a path like '/users/1234' where you're looking for a user with that key but he's not in the system.  Perhaps that user key will be there tomorrow.  But the wrong path is definitely wrong.

Comment: I'll tell you right now I have no idea how to do this with Jersey, but I doubt very much it is possible out of the box. However, I'd like to try and convince you that 404 is the appropriate code. The HTTP spec says `The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.` about a 404. The resource `/foobar` would not exist. There's nothing bad about the request. The server understands it, but there is no corresponding resource for it.

Comment: A Bad Request means `The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.` That doesn't seem to be the case in the example you've given. It doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis hm I think I understand.  The syntax is fine so it shouldn't be a 400.  Technically this question is unanswered, so I suppose I'll leave it open, but I no longer want to change the default.