# Java Jersey: how to change response for wrong url?

Tags: java, url, exception, jersey, http-status-code-404

Client asks `"/game"` page.

Server doesn't have that page and drops `NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found`.

How to catch(?) that exception and change for, example, 401?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can refer to the answer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583973/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-customize-error-handling

Thanks