# Returning multiple values and status/error from a function

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a server which receives requests that I have to parse in order to get the parameters for the request handler to use. Also, both the parsing and the request handler could fail in some way (e.g.: for the parser, a parameter is missing; for the req. handler: some error in a database), hence the "status" in the code below. The request handler of course gives some kind of response which I then have to send back to the client.

So I'm having trouble deciding which of the following options I should use in my "main", because I want to keep the parser separated from the handler:

1)

```
parser.parse(request,&param1, &param2, &status)

handler.handle(param1, param2, &response, &status)
```

2)

```
status = parser.parse(request, &param1, &param2)

status = handler.handle(param1, param2, &response)
```

3)

```
Params params = parser.parse(request, &status)

handler.handle(params, &response, &status)
```

4)

```
status = parser.parse(request, &params)

status = handler.handle(params, &response)
```

5)

```
parser.parse(request, &params, &status)

response = handler.handle(params, &status)
```

6) etc., some other combination

(Params would be some kind of container for the different parameters, so for each type of request I would have a different "Params" type. Also, the "&" could mean pointer or reference, I'm using c++, but it's not relevant to the question)

Which is the easiest, clearer, best, ...,  whatever?

*** There are plenty of similar questions, but none include the "status" part, so I can't make my mind yet

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a language-agnostic as it dependent on language features. For example, in Java I would do this like:

```
try {
    Params params = parser.parse(request); // parser.parse will throw ParseException if something wrong
    Response response = handler.handle(params); // handler.handle will throw HandleException if something wrong
    // send response to the client (status 200)
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // Send parse error to the client (for example: status 400 with e.getMessage() as message)
} catch (HandleException e) {
    // Send handle error to the client (for example: status 500 with e.getMessage() as message)
}
```

So the `status` is just an exception if it is bad status and no exception if it is good status. This can be custom exception with `status` field for more detail.

If programming language can't use the exceptions, then you can use pass by value (`&status`) for example. But don't pass the result, returning the status. Return the result. The result of `parse` is parsed params, not the status.

Comment: The thing is, an error is not necessarily an exception. For example, if a user wants to login with a wrong password, I wouldn't say that is an "exception". Here the Response would be a token, and it doesn't seem ok to return a null token if the password is wrong.

Comment: If a user tries to login with a wrong password, it is definitely an exception, which should resolve to 401/403 http status. And password-checking  function will not return `null`. It will throw an exception (returning nothing). Do you know how exceptions work? If the function throws an exception, it not returns `null`. It returns nothing and code execution flow jumps to `catch` block.

Comment: Yes, I know how exceptions work. I just don't think a wrong password is an exception, as it is not exceptional at all, it is very common for a user to enter  a wrong password. So what I meant was that in your code there is no way to tell if something went wrong but didn't throw an exception.

Comment: Сommonness of exception does not make it not an exception. :) It is common practice to make some set of exceptions which method could throw. Check, for example JAX-RS's [NotAuthorizedException](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/NotAuthorizedException.html). Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583973/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-customize-error-handling) answer. Or Spring's [BadCredentialsException](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/BadCredentialsException.html). It's just how it works.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @Chrischpo ... Exceptions should be used for ***exceptional*** circumstances. Incorrect password is hardly exceptional. In fact, if you're security conscious, you would have a number of specific use-cases dealing with authentication failure (not incorrect password): logging, tracking retry counts, account lockout. (This is not the sort of code you should be calling from with a **catch** block.)