# How to show exception message in postman?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, postman

I am getting list of products from DB using REST Webservice Call & checking if products are NULL or NOT.

IF there are no products i need to throw an exception in POSTMAN.

Can anyone throw some light on how to show exception messages in postman?

Code:

```
public class ABC extends BusinessException
{
    public ABC(final String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    public ABC(final String message, final Throwable cause)
    {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: add a list of Strings called errorMessages to your response object, catch the exception(s) you get, and add their messages to that list

Comment: @Stultuske I had done this..exception getting printed on console but not in POSTMAN

Comment: @User2413 how you did that? Show the code.

Comment: @User2413 had you done this, it wouldn't. could you show your code?

Comment: Following answer might be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/599131/6234057

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use **WebApplicationException** from jax-rs to throw the exception

For Example:

```java
if(products==null){
 throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("products does not exist.").build());
}
```

If you have your custom exception then you can extends WebApplicationException

```java
public class BusinessException extends WebApplicationException {
     public BusinessException(Response.Status status, String message) {
         super(Response.status(status)
             .entity(message).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build());
     }
}
```

throw from your code

```java
 if(products==null){
      throw new BusinessException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND,"products does not exist.");
 }
```

you can use error response object to display clean way

```java
public class ErrorResponse {
  private int status;
  private String message;
  ErrorResponse(int status,String message){
     this.status = status;
     this.message = message;
  }
//setters and getters here
}
```

create ErrorResponse object while throwing the exception

```java
public class BusinessException extends WebApplicationException {
     public BusinessException(Response.Status status, String message) {
         super(Response.status(status)
             .entity(new ErrorResponse(status.getStatusCode(),message)).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
     }
}
```

In postman it will display like below

```
{
  status:404,
  message:"products does not exist."
}
```